# extracting unique values from a column with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, email, merge

I have data where im trying to extract unique values from one column for each set of my customers. i want to use the data to do a mail merge . for instance column A has multiple entries for each customer name. so in column A cells a1:a6 all say "abc company" the cells a7:a11 all say "X company". in column B it has a recommended part number list. so b1:b3 all say "01-ssc-011" then b3:b5 all say 01-ssc-044 then b5:b8 all say "01-ssc-011" and finally b8:b11 all say 01-ssc-044"

how would i extract the unique part numbers for each set of customers. I want to essentially delete duplicate instances of part number PER CUSTOMER and leave only unique part numbers for each customer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwlTi.png)

Comment: Data -> Remove Duplicates

Comment: You won't need to extract them, just remove duplicates right there and then through the build-in feature

Comment: any luck on the tries ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no other data in other cell/column.

Select column A&B > Data > Remove duplicates.

Please share if it works/not. ( :